How to awk so that rest of the line stays intact?
I have line
* {@jira: PIVOT-9968} Provide a way to pass an `IMemoryCollector` to `IInternalMemoryMonitored#getMemoryStatistics(memoryCollector)` in order to prevent the count of duplicated blocks.

I wanted to  escape only the first containing the ticket(?) number.
write script to add backslash
for my previous problem
* /{@jira: PIVOT-9968/} Provide a way to pass an `IMemoryCollector` to `IInternalMemoryMonitored#getMemoryStatistics(memoryCollector)` in order to prevent the count of duplicated blocks.

I tried
mawk '/^\* {@jira: PIVOT/ { gsub(/[{} ]/,"\\\\&") } 1' changelog.md > tmp && mv tmp changelog.md

and got
*\ \{@jira:\ PIVOT-8019\}\ Pivot:\ Added\ `MaxAppendOnlyFunction`\ and\ \ `MinAppendOnlyFunction`\ aggregation\ functions\ that\ do\ not\ support\ disaggregation\ but\ can\ be\ used\ within\ an\ aggregate\ provider.

what should I change? gsub?

What exactly do you mean with "Eds answer", can you provide a link to that?

edited,take a look pls, now line is different and I showed what I need.

gsub(/[{} ]/,"\\\\&") -- you are explicitly asking for spaces to be escaped. Is that not what you want? Your goal is unclear.

Dou you want to escape every occurence of { and }, or only the first containing the ticket(?) number? Please edit your question to clarify.

@AdminBee edited,only the first and that the rest keeps the same.

the expected output shows a forward slash as the escape character but the mawk script implies you wish to use a backward slash as the escape character; which is it ... forward or backward slash? please update the question to address this confusion

It's very important when providing sample input/output to also includes lines you do NOT want to match as it's always much easier to write a script to match text you want to match than to not match similar text you do not want to match. That's why you're having to ask multiple questions about this same problem - your previous questions didn't include examples of text you don't want to match (e.g. the text after the {...}) and I suspect this question also doesn't include examples of text you don't want to match (e.g. lines that don't start with * but may contain { and/or }).

In awk

sub() will replace the first occurrence of a match
gsub() will replace all occurrences of a match
/[{} ]/ says to match on any 1 of 3 characters: {, } and   (single space)

If we remove the space (leaving us with /{}/):
$ awk '/^\* {@jira: PIVOT/ { gsub(/[{}]/,"\\\\&") } 1' changelog.md
* \{@jira: PIVOT-9968\} Provide a way to pass an `IMemoryCollector` to `IInternalMemoryMonitored#getMemoryStatistics(memoryCollector)` in order to prevent the count of duplicated blocks.

Assuming OP wants to use a back slash as the escape character, and there will only be the one pair of braces on the line, this should be sufficient to address OP's requirement.
If multiple pairs of braces can occur in a line ...
$ cat changelog_2.md
* {@jira: PIVOT-1234} new line {with several} sets of braces {for demonstration} purposes

Running the new code against this file will erroneously modify all pairs of braces:
$ awk '/^\* {@jira: PIVOT/ { gsub(/[{}]/,"\\\\&") } 1' changelog_2.md
* \{@jira: PIVOT-1234\} new line \{with several\} sets of braces \{for demonstration\} purposes

To limit the replacements to just the first pair of braces we can use a pair of sub() calls where each call replaces the first occurrence of a single character; notice that we replace /[{}]/ with /{/ and /}/ and since we know the character we'll be matching on we can replace \\& with the actual character (for a slight simplification in the code):
$ awk '/^\* {@jira: PIVOT/ { sub(/{/,"\\{"); sub(/}/,"\\}") } 1' changelog_2.md
* \{@jira: PIVOT-1234\} new line {with several} sets of braces {for demonstration} purposes

Implementing this last one-at-a-time replacement with sed:
$ sed 's/}/\\}/1; s/{/\\{/1' changelog.md changelog_2.md
* \{@jira: PIVOT-9968\} Provide a way to pass an `IMemoryCollector` to `IInternalMemoryMonitored#getMemoryStatistics(memoryCollector)` in order to prevent the count of duplicated blocks.
* \{@jira: PIVOT-1234\} new line {with several} sets of braces {for demonstration} purposes

Where:

the trailing /1 says to replace the first occurrence
as with the awk / sub() approach we need to run two separate replacements to match the first pair of braces


The { in awk '/^\* \{@ is undefined behavior as awk expects { to be the start of a regexp interval like {3}. It needs to be awk '/^\* \{@ to be portable. Similarly sub(/{/,"\\{") needs to be sub(/\{/,"\\{")

This might be what you're trying to do, using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and gensub():
$ awk '
    match($0, /^(\* )(\{[^{}]+})(.*)/, a) {
        $0 = a[1] gensub(/[{} ]/, "\\\\&", "g", a[2]) a[3]
    }
    { print }
' file
* \{@jira:\ PIVOT-9968\} Provide a way to pass an `IMemoryCollector` to `IInternalMemoryMonitored#getMemoryStatistics(memoryCollector)` in order to prevent the count of duplicated blocks.

or this using any awk:
$ awk '
    match($0, /^\* \{[^{}]+}/) {
        tgt = substr($0,3,RLENGTH-2)
        gsub(/[{} ]/, "\\\\&", tgt)
        $0 = substr($0,1,2) tgt substr($0,RLENGTH+1)
    }
    { print }
' file
* \{@jira:\ PIVOT-9968\} Provide a way to pass an `IMemoryCollector` to `IInternalMemoryMonitored#getMemoryStatistics(memoryCollector)` in order to prevent the count of duplicated blocks.

but with just 1 line of sample input it's hard to guess.
